# Debugging install4j works on linux but not on windows?

Tags: windows, logging, install4j

Why doesn't *-Dinstall4j.debug=true -Dinstall4j.logToStderr=true* on windows result in messages in the console while it does on linux?

My cross platform installer runs as a normal user on linux and elevates on windows so it can install a service.

*Linux*

```
myinstaller.sh  -Dinstall4j.debug=true -Dinstall4j.logToStderr=true
```

Console window fills with useful information

*Windows*

```
myinstaller.exe  -Dinstall4j.debug=true -Dinstall4j.logToStderr=true
```

console window empty - I suspect the elevation, which seems to require a relaunch, is the cause.

If I run my installer from an Admin window I don't get my error case and don't see the console logging either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI applications cannot write to the console under Windows, because they have no associated console.

If you select the "Windows console executable" property for the installer node on the Installer->Screens & Actions tab, you will see console output.